# Netbeans ide for development modules in Play!

Tags: playframework

Hi I started to use Play Framework and I want to develop modules to use my next projects using Netbeans IDE. But when I write "play netbeansify my-module" command, I get "Oops. conf/routes or conf/application.conf missing." error. Does play support netbeans for developing modules? if not How can I develop new modules.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am the author of the Elastic Search, LinkedIn, RabbitMQ and Log4Play mods.
You can define a routes a file in a module. The routes defined in a module can then be imported into the application which using the module.

Per-definition a module doesn't have an application.conf because it's not an application. During development I like to define an application.conf so I can run as an independent application, then just remove it when you are packing the module.

Just remember that class auto-reload won't work for classes packages inside a jar (example: classes defined outside dir "app").

Thanks,
Felipe
http://geeks.aretotally.in